# Outputting 2D array to form using TableLayout Panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to output a 2D array to a form using the tablelayout panel, however when I run the code I have written to do this, the form shows nothing (although no errors are actually thrown up when running it), so I am unsure as to why this isn't working?

Here's my code:

```
Sub OutputUsingTableLayoutPanel(ByRef arrtruthtable(,) As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim TableRowsToAdd As Integer = itruthtablerows - 1
    Dim TableColumnsToAdd As Integer = itruthtablecolumns - 1
    Dim NewLabel As New Label()

    TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))

    Do Until i = TableColumnsToAdd
        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount += 1
        i += 1
    Loop

    Do Until j = TableRowsToAdd
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1
        j += 1
    Loop

    Do Until k = TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount
        Do Until l = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(NewLabel, k, l)
            NewLabel.Name = "lbl" & k & l
            NewLabel.Text = arrtruthtable(k, l)
            l += 1
        Loop
        k += 1
        l = 0
    Loop

End Sub
```

Any help or ideas as to why this isn't working would be much appreciated!

Comment: A lot of things wrong here, adding the same label to multiple cells certainly won't work.  Just don't do this, use a ListView with View = Details or a DataGridView.

Comment: Just an aside, but there is no need to pass in `arrtruthtable` in ByRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to consider in your code:

`ColumnCount` and `RowCount` are integer properties that you can manipulate directly.

You should declare `NewLabel` inside the inner loop so that each one that gets added is a new object.

You should set the properties of `NewLabel` before you add it to the tablelayoutpanel

For loops, for this type of iteration, are much more intuitive and easier to read.

2 dimensional arrays index by row,column but the tablelayoutpanel uses column,row

When you need to access an array that's being passed into your sub routine you can get the length of the individual dimensions rather than relying on a global variable.

here's some revised code to look at:

```
    Dim test(,) As String = {{"A", "A1"}, {"B", "B1"}, {"C", "C1"}}
    OutputUsingTableLayoutPanel(test)

Sub OutputUsingTableLayoutPanel(ByRef arrtruthtable(,) As String)

    Dim TableRowsToAdd As Integer = arrtruthtable.GetLength(0)
    Dim TableColumnsToAdd As Integer = arrtruthtable.GetLength(1)

    TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = TableColumnsToAdd
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = TableRowsToAdd

    For k = 0 To TableColumnsToAdd - 1
        For l = 0 To TableRowsToAdd - 1
            Dim NewLabel As New Label()
            NewLabel.Name = "lbl" & k & l
            NewLabel.Text = arrtruthtable(l, k)
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(NewLabel, k, l)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Here's a simple way to get the formatting even:

```
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = TableColumnsToAdd
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = TableRowsToAdd
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear()
    For I = 1 To TableRowsToAdd
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 \ TableRowsToAdd))
    Next
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear()
    For I = 1 To TableColumnsToAdd
        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 \ TableColumnsToAdd))
    Next
```

Comment: The 2D array doesn't necessarily mean that the array has 2 columns?

Comment: Sorry got my terminology mixed up a bit

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but when the code runs it works through both the inner and outer loops the correct number of times, but then the final output to the console only seems to show 2 rows and 2 columns (which is what is defined in the form design), almost as if the extra columns/rows are not being created at runtime?

Comment: I made some revisions see if they help.  One thing to consider.  If you are changing things in the form Load event and there is an error, the execution won't stop it will just exit the sub routine and finish loading the form as is.  However if you pay attention to the error list it will show which exception was thrown.

Comment: There is now nothing being outputted to the form, but also no exceptions being thrown (according to the immediate window)?

Comment: Edit your original post and add the code you're now using.  The code I showed you works for me.  I'll have to see what you've done to see where the error is.

Comment: The code I'm using is identical to the code you posted above?

Comment: Since I know that the code works, check the array and make sure it is being filled.  I added code for a simple array to test the sub routine with.

Comment: Ah yeah the code does work, it was just that the size of the tablelayoutpanel elements were too small for the contents of my array to fit into! Thanks!